# Socket.IO cannot establish a connection

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I use socket.io-client for Javascript server on JAVA and when I enter address 'ws://10.201.223.67:9902/' the request is not by 'ws' but by 'http'.
[image]

It returns
[image]

Although I understand it should just come back 0
[image]

It keeps trying to connect.To connect using my own written hook

```
export function useSocketIO(url: string) {
const ioRef = useRef<Socket>();
const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
ioRef.current = io(url, {
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${APIAuth.accessToken}`,
      },
    },
  },
});
ioRef.current.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('WS Connected to', url);
  setConnected(() => true);
});

ioRef.current.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('WS disconnected');
  setConnected(() => false);
});

return () => {
  console.log('WS destroyed');
  ioRef.current?.close();
};
}, [url]);

return {
io: ioRef.current,
connected,
 };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework to handle the websocket? Java can't do this natively, it doesn't know what the `ws://` protocol is.

Comment: As I was told that this is implemented through soket.io.Through postman connection to the server java happens.And with javaScript client in JS I get what is on the screenshots.No way I can not understand what could be the problem.